# golang bug with sprintf when giving string as argument to %09d

Tags: go, printf

Why doesnt this give a compile error, is it a bug in golang or do I miss something?

```
intPadded := fmt.Sprintf("%09d", "i am a string" )
fmt.Println("bah" + intPadded)
```

when executed it gives

```
bah%!d(string=i am a string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If an invalid argument is given for a verb, such as providing a string to %d, the generated string will contain a description of the problem" per http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

It doesn't give a compile-time error because there is no compile-time error. `fmt.Sprintf()` is defined as taking `...interface{}` for its last argument, which is valid for any sequence of types. The checking is done only at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

It's your bug. The compiler can only check that the `fmt.Sprintf` arguments have the proper type; all types implement the empty interface. Use the Go `vet` command.

> [func Sprintf](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf)
>
> `func Sprintf(format string, a ...interface{}) string`
>
> Sprintf formats according to a format specifier and returns the
>   resulting string.
>
> [Interface types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)
>
> An interface type specifies a method set called its interface. A
>   variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method
>   set that is any superset of the interface. Such a type is said to
>   implement the interface.
>
> A type implements any interface comprising any subset of its methods
>   and may therefore implement several distinct interfaces. For instance,
>   all types implement the empty interface:
>
> ```
> interface{}
> ```
>
> [Command vet](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/vet)
>
> Vet examines Go source code and reports suspicious constructs, such as
>   Printf calls whose arguments do not align with the format string.